GCP Oauth for notification without libraries
Recently google asked to switch from FCM to http V1:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1
The docs is very clear , if you can use the credentials.json file.
The problem is that I have a backend that does not support ANY google lib, so i need to use the oauth.
How can I integrate it?
